# status bar with icons to simulate home or power button press

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3

i'm rooted on android 4.0.4 ICS stock. 
i would like to have a status bar that even shows in full screen, which can have an icon to simulate a home button press and an icon to simulate a power button press. anyone know of an available way to do this on this rom or another rom? 
thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen off app: [Screen Off and Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katecca.screenofflock&hl=en_US)

Then, something like [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle) can be used to have this icon and others in the notification dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You always can install [Button Savior](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey) on rooted ROMs (however I'm not aware if it has compatibility problems with some). It worths a try, because it's free (but also has a pro version to purchase).

It allows you to add hardware keys of your phone as virtual software keys on any location of the screen. So you can easily trigger home or back keys just by touching their icons on screen, even on full-screen apps and games.

Comment: thanks, but i had tried that one. it doesn't/didn't work for me since i was unable to have the icon in the status bar. having something in the status bar would allow the quick-press access and not obscure the viewing of the active app.

Comment: OK, I remember it had also an option to hide the buttons and reveal them only when you touch a tiny trigger button, so your screen won't be obscured. Have you tried that option? I currently haven't installed the app and can't say you the exact address, but you would find it in settings.

Comment: the 'trigger' or initial icon to be clicked is what i would like to have in the status bar. 0% obscurity and always-access is the goal for the icon for home/power.

Comment: I just installed "Button Savior" to check the case. You are right, it can't be placed on top or bottom, just left or right. May the developer would add that option if you ask him, because I think it hasn't any technical limitations.

Comment: thanks for your confirmation. perhaps, i do need to wait on something to be developed. i just posted this question to see if there's something already existing.